# Turn on viewstate for a single page

Tags: asp.net, viewstate

I have a website created using VS2017 - it's based on Asp.Net 4.7.

All of my pages inherit from the main master page - it includes all the header stuff which I don't want to repeat over.

Most of my pages don't need viewstate but one page in particular does.

Ideally I'd like to enable viewstate as the exception, but I'm finding it pretty difficult to achieve.

Firstly, I disabled viewstate in web.config.

I then tried to re-enable viewstate for the page in both the web.config (using location) and on the aspx page itself. Both unsuccessful.

I've read a few articles that imply this behaviour could be down to the use of a master page, which seems to be confirms with the tests I've perfeormed.

If that is the case, It leaves my with two rather cumbersome options:

1. disable viewstate on each page;
2. remove the reliance on the master page and 'duplicate everything
   within the page that requires viewstate.

**However, I may have missed something, or misunderstood what I've already read.**

So, before going down either of these routes, I'd appreciate it if anyone could advise as to whether there are any other solutions to this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly is your question? You can enable/disable ViewState on every level. Master, Page, Control etc. And it inherits from the above level.

Comment: if viewstate is disabled at web.config level, it does not allow re-enabling either in the aspx page or by adding a location override in the web.config. That is what I've found in my scenario using a master page - which has been tested.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a way to fix this issue that wasn't cumbersome.

However, I did come up with a solution. All of my web pages are stored in a database, so I appended a new column 'EnableViewState' and now enable it programatically on a page by page basis.